# Sourcing .bashrc in Docker via ENTRYPOINT

Tags: python, bash, docker, conda

I have created an image with a bash script called by `ENTRYPOINT` that itself launches an executable from a `conda` environment. I'm building this from a single layer directly (for now) which I realize is not best practice, but let's ignore that for a hot second...

Dockerfile

```
 FROM alexholehouse/seq_demo:demo_early
 SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
 ENTRYPOINT ["/seq_demo/launcher/launcher.sh"]
```

Where `launcher.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

# source bashrc which includes conda init section (and works fine in an interactive terminal)
source /root/.bashrc

# activate the conda environment
conda activate custom_conda

if [ -d /mount ]
then
    cd /mount

    # run the executable from the conda environment
    demo_seq -k KEYFILE.kf
else
    echo "No storage mounted..."
fi
```

Now the problem is that when I build the image using the above Dockerfile, the `.bashrc` file doesn't get sourced because of the following (standard) line at the top of `.bashrc`.

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

... <bashrc stuff>

__conda_setup="$('/root/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

So running the image using

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/mount b29c47a060
```

Means `.bashrc` is not sourced and the `launcher.sh` fails because conda can't be found.

If, on the other hand, I edit `.bashrc` so all the conda stuff is *above* the `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` line then (a) conda gets sourced and (b) the rest of the .bashrc is read too.

Now, editing `.bashrc` solves my issue but *this cannot be the right way to do this*! So, what's the correct way to set up an image/Dockerfile so:

(a) A specific bash script gets run upon running the container and 
(b) That bash script sources the `.bashrc`

I feel like I'm just missing something super obvious here...

Comment: Have you tried `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]`? That should source the `.bashrc` automatically, without needing it in the script. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

$PS1 is containing your command prompt (symbol/ e.g. '#: ').
[Example of changing prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOeZV.png)

So you have to figure out why PS1 isnt set in the first place. Because `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` will exit the script only when $PS1 is not set at all.

When the baseimage youre using doesnt provide any you might just add on in your Dockerfile via `ENV PS1`.

In case you never ever login into your container to use command line you might just drop that check.

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43950/why-bash-profile-couldnt-set-ps1-variable) for more information about how PS1 is propagated in bash.